# Equality on abstract data types

Tags: haskell

If I have:

```
data Container a = Node a | End a | Container a
```

if I wanted to write a function which could look at a list of Container a elements and perform a list difference, how would I do this so that I can explicitly tell the compiler that this abstract data type allows equality?

I thought it would be:

```
compare::Eq (Container a) => Container a -> Container a -> Bool
compare a b
           | a == b = True
           | a /= b = False
```

but it complains about the Eq statement not being correct because it could not deduce (Eq (Container a)) arising from use of '=='

EDIT it seems deriving (Eq) in my abstract data type is the only way to allow this. Can somebody please confirm?

EDIT2 after including deriving (Eq):

```
test:: [Container a] -> Container a -> Bool
test list element = elem element list
```

> "No instance for (Eq a)"

Answer (score 6):

The easiest way to inform the compiler of instances like these is to use [a `deriving` clause](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Classes_and_types#Deriving). In this case,

```
data Container a = Node a | End a | Container a deriving (Eq)
```

One can also give an `Eq` instance by hand, e.g. the following says that if a `Container` contains elements that can be tested for equality, then the `Container` can also be tested for equality.

```
instance Eq a => Eq (Container a) where
    (Node a)      == (Node b)      = a == b
    (End a)       == (End b)       = a == b
    (Container a) == (Container b) = a == b
    _             == _             = False
```

This is the same definition as the one `deriving` gives, so it isn't necessary to type out definitions like that ever, but if one wants a more complicated definition of `Eq` then one must do something like that.

Once you have an `Eq` instance for container, you can just write:

```
compare :: Eq a => Container a -> Container a -> Bool
compare a b | a == b = True
            | a /= b = False
```

(Two things about this function: it is actually entirely pointless, since it is the same as `(==)`, and one should use `otherwise` as the last alternative in guards.)

Those are basically the only two options. Although there is a third method, which is essentially a combination of the two: using the GHC extension [`StandaloneDeriving`](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/GHC/StandAloneDeriving).

```
deriving instance Eq a => Eq (Container a)
```

Comment: I have added deriving (Eq) to my abstract data type. I then create the function which checks whether an element is within the container, using elem. So I have a list of Container a elements and one Container a element. When I use elem list element, it says "No instance for (Container a)

Comment: I have added my second function to the original post under Edit2

Comment: Your list is of `a`, not `Container a` in that function.

Comment: Sorry, just updated it. Yet I still get an error message relating to "a"

Comment: Look at the signature I have given for `compare` in my answer, and also, remove the type signature from `test`, load the file into GHCi and then use `:t test` to show you the inferred type.

Comment: Ok but the problem is that I will have to declare Eq a => in every single function involved in the invocation of compare/test?

Comment: @Dan, yes, you will have to make that declaration.

Answer (score 1):

As for "No instance for (Eq a)" - your type is wrong.

```
test:: [Container a] -> Container a -> Bool
```

The type says that you can compare *any* containers which is wrong. Your current instance is only available for containers having comparable elements. So you should write

```
test:: Eq a => [Container a] -> Container a -> Bool
```